# Free up memory once Thread finished its task

Tags: c#

Put break point before `Thread` start and you will notice console consuming about 5 to 8 MB memory but once `Thread` started it spike to 17 to 20 MB memory. And this memory stay used until close console. How can i freeup memory after `Thread` finished it task? Any better solution?

Now question is: Why i need it since garbage collector will automatically free up memory when needed. I need it because i am doing web scraping and i got a global class to store all scraped html text there and i have to scrape like 10k pages and store that html to global class. What happen is: when i run this app after scrape 500 html data to global class it eat almost 100% of my pc RAM which is 20 GB. So i need to free up RAM. I cant close console app to free up ram bcoz i have some calculation after collect all html.

```
class DemoData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public static List<DemoData> data = new List<DemoData>();
    }

    class Program
    {
        

        public static void Main()
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            {
                DemoData.data.Add(new DemoData
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Text = "something....",
                });
                
            }

            foreach (var item in DemoData.data)
            {
                var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));//put break point here and see.
                t.Name = item.Id.ToString(); ;
                t.Start();
            }

            
            Console.WriteLine("wait");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

     
        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            Thread thr = Thread.CurrentThread;
            Console.WriteLine(thr.Name);
            
        }


    }
```

Comment: The garbage collector handles that for you. It will free up garbage when it needs to...ie cuz it's under load etc. There's no need here yet, so it doesn't bother. Unless you profile your app and determine there's a memory issue then these sorta things should not matter to you. Let the runtime do its job

Comment: You don't freeup manually. The Garbage Collector will take care of it when the objects are not needed and there is pressure that memory is required. Also you should use Tasks over Threads for asynchronous operations or Parallel.For for parallel processing. Threads in general should not be used.

Comment: you need to wait for for the garbage collector to run, the framework will fire this off when it feels it is needed, this will then look though the callstack and decide which objects it no longer needs and delete them freeing up memory, this will happen completely automatically with out you needing to do anything. if you want to help the GC out you can check your variable scopes so that the GC can see its not needed anymore because its completely out of scope

Comment: @MikeT - the JIT and GC already work together such that when a variable will no longer be read from it is no longer considered "live" from a garbage perspective. You really don't need to "help out" the GC. E.g. an object can be collected *whilst it's still being constructed*, if the constructor no longer uses the `this` reference and the newly constructed object isn't used afterwards. That's how efficient it is.

Comment: Question updated guys! Please check.

Comment: If it's not freeing up memory when it should, you have a memory leak. You fix that with a profiler and bug fixes, not through some magical "free memory now" code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if you are writting good code yes, if you are saving everything into global variables and doing other ill advised things then the GC can start to struggle with whats in and out of scope

Comment: @JohnBrk the problem is that you are using a global variable, this is a very bad idea for anything data intense as you have basically tags all the memory as required and non disposable instead you should process a chunk of data save it to the permanent stare either file, database and then dispose of the data this will then allow it to be cleaned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to wait for for the `garbage collector` to run, your current app isn't complex enough to require this except on close so you aren't seeing this occur,

so the framework will fire off the GC when it feels it is needed, this will then look though the callstack and decide which objects it no longer needs and delete them freeing up memory, this will happen completely automatically with out you needing to do anything.

if you want to help the GC out you can check your variable scopes so that the GC can see its not needed anymore because its completely out of scope, so avoiding global variables, not creating links between data objects that aren't needed making correct choices between value and reference types, ect

however if you ever do end up in a position where you need to manually fire the GC you can call GC.Collect()
see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-5.0

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with GC.  He's starting 5000 threads, each requires 4 MB of address space for their stack in 64-bit mode. 5000 * 4 MB = 20 GB.

Comment: @HansPassant you are correct. Thats the thing i think. Whats the solution?

Comment: You could ignore it, that's just address space that's reserved so doesn't take RAM and doesn't take paging file space.  But certainly -10000 elegance points, matching the elegance of starting 5000 threads.  Use the threadpool or distribute work with a BlockingCollection over, say, 4 threads.

Comment: @HansPassant we all agree that the issues isn't the GC, howeer this is the answer to the question they asked, and will be the right answer for anyone else looking for manually manage the GC, however now we are getting away from what they thought was the issue to what the actual problem is

Comment: @JohnBrk  theere are a few options depending on how the program you write works, you can either just reduce the number of tasks to a manageable number or if you have 2 tasks that feed into each other then have a look at the link to Channels that i provided this will provide a thread safe way to queue your data for each thread to access especially if you create a managed channel, then it will pause the feeder process while the processor catches up

Comment: Ok i am trying to implement @MikeT provided blog link

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a memory profiler to check for potential memory leaks.

A possible reason for your issues is the large number of threads, there is no reason to use more threads than there are cpu cores. Each thread used will need some memory for a stack and other house keeping.

One fairly simple way would be to put addresses that needs visiting in a collection, and use a [parallel.Foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-5.0). This will try to adjust the number of threads used to maximize thruput. More complex variants could use one of the concurrent collections and multiple consumers. There is also async variants of many IO calls to avoid the memory overhead of blocking a thread while waiting for IO. I would recommend reading some examples of multiple producers/consumers pattern for more details.

Comment: doubt there is an actual memory leak you have to be mucking around with unmanaged memory to get that, just beginner error on thread management

Comment: @MikeT it is fairly easy to forget to detach event handlers or do something else that may cause a memory leak. So while the reason is probably poor thread management, using a memory profiler should in most cases be the first step to take and is a valuable skill to learn.

Comment: ah we are working of different definitions of memory leak

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is feeding the data into the threads for processing then i would suggest you look at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/ this allows you to then create a thread safe processing buffer

here is working example, note this is using the .net 5 syntax

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

var sites = Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).Select(i => @"http:\\www.example.com");

//create thread safe buffer no limit on size
var sitebuffer = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
//create thread safe buffer limited to 10 elements
var htmlbuffer = Channel.CreateBounded<string>(10);

async Task Feed()
{
    //while the buffer hasn't closed, wait for new data to be available
    while(await sitebuffer.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
    {
        //read the next available url from the buffer
        var uri = await sitebuffer.Reader.ReadAsync();
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var html= await http.GetAsync(uri);
        Console.WriteLine("reading site");
        //load the return text to the htmlbuffer, if buffer is full wait for space
        await htmlbuffer.Writer.WriteAsync(await html.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        Console.WriteLine("reading site complete");
    }
}
 async Task Process()
{
    //while the buffer hasn't closed, wait for new data to be available
    while (await htmlbuffer.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
    {
        //read html from buffer send to doSomething then read next element
        var html = await htmlbuffer.Reader.ReadAsync();
        await doSomethingWithHTML(html);
    }
}

async Task doSomethingWithHTML(string html)
{
    await Task.Delay(2);
    Console.WriteLine("done something");
}

//start 4 feeders threads
var feeders = new[]
{
    Feed(),
    Feed(),
    Feed(),
    Feed(),
};
//start 2 worker threads
var workers = new[]
{
    Process(),
    Process(),
};
//start of feeding in sites
foreach (var item in sites)
{
    await sitebuffer.Writer.WriteAsync(item);
}
//mark that all sites have been fed into the systems
sitebuffer.Writer.Complete();

//wait for all feeders to finish
await Task.WhenAll(feeders);
//mark that no more sites will be read
htmlbuffer.Writer.Complete();
//wait for all workers to finish
await Task.WhenAll(workers);

Console.WriteLine("all tasks complete");
```

notice the `async Task`'s and `awaits` this is a newer wrapper around threads that simplifies a lot of the complexity in managing threads